# How to write a file I/O hook in C#

Tags: c#, windows, file, io, buffer

Let me explain the problem. Application X (which is not mine) want to read/write file F from hard disk. I want an application/library M to act as a buffer in between so every write will be buffered and every read will be redirected to M. How is this possible? I think I need to somehow hook my C# methods to windows file I/O events.

Some notes:

- I cannot change application X
- I cannot change path of contents of file F

I thought that it might be possible to implement something similar to RAM-Disks but for a file.

Comment: I/O operations in C# are performed through .NET methods, which are eventually delegated to the Windows Kernel. As none of these are open-source, you can't not change the default behavior. The only option is from Application X to reference your application and perform its I/O operations through Application M.

Comment: Your question feels a bit too broad for SO. If indeed you figure out you need to hook calls - check out http://easyhook.codeplex.com/

Comment: The OS will *already* buffer IO access, and most modern hard drives will as well.  If you want to intercept all file IO and actually change the content, then that would be a *major* security flaw if the OS let you do that.  You'd pretty much need to write your own OS to be able to do that.

Comment: You could also look at Dokan  https://code.google.com/p/dokan/

Comment: @Servy - writing a [file system minifilter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would enable you to do just that by intercepting IRP packets. That's unmanaged, kernel-mode software, but it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody. I think a combination of [ImDisk Virtual Disk Driver](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk) and [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html#contact) can be a viable solution. I create a virtual ram disk and move file F to that location. Then I use Link Shell Extension to create a link to F in the folder that needs to be seen by application X. By that way, file is located inside RAM and everything is transparent from application X. More importantly I do not need to write even 1 line of code :)